# Concatenating two linked lists in Rust

Tags: rust, linked-list

I have an enum like the following:

```
#[derive(Clone,PartialEq,Debug)]
pub enum List<T> {
    Nil,
    Cons(T,Box<List<T>>)
}
```

Next I want to concat two of these Lists together so:

```
let x1 = 
            List::Cons(0,
                Box::new(List::Cons(1,
                Box::new(List::Cons(2,
                Box::new(List::Cons(3,
                Box::new(List::Nil))))))));
        let x2 = 
            List::Cons(4,
                Box::new(List::Cons(5,
                Box::new(List::Cons(6,
                Box::new(List::Nil))))));
```

concat(&x1,&x2)

Gives me:

```
List::Cons(0,
                Box::new(List::Cons(1,
                Box::new(List::Cons(2,
                Box::new(List::Cons(3,
                Box::new(List::Cons(4,
                Box::new(List::Cons(5,
                Box::new(List::Cons(6,
                Box::new(List::Nil))))))))))))));
```

Currently I have:

```
pub fn concat<T:Copy>(l1:& List<T>,l2:& List<T>) -> List<T> {
    let my_list = l1.clone();
    let result = concat_helper(my_list, l2);
    return result;
}

//Helper functions
pub fn concat_helper<T:Copy>(my_list:List<T>, l2:& List<T>) -> List<T>{
    match l2 {
        List::Nil => my_list,
        List::Cons(h, t) => List::Cons(*h, Box::new(concat_helper(my_list, t)))
    }
}
```

Which would concat List2 to List1, which gives:

```
List::Cons(4,
    Box::new(List::Cons(5,
    Box::new(List::Cons(6,
    Box::new(List::Cons(0,
    Box::new(List::Cons(1,
    Box::new(List::Cons(2,
    Box::new(List::Cons(3,
    Box::new(List::Nil))))))))))))));
```

Which is not what I want. How would I go about correcting this code?

Note: some people have suggested I change it to:

```
pub fn concat<T:Copy>(l1:& List<T>,l2:& List<T>) -> List<T> {
    let my_list = l1.clone();
    let result = concat_helper(my_list, l2);
    return result;
}

//Helper functions
pub fn concat_helper<T:Copy>(my_list:List<T>, l2:& List<T>) -> List<T>{
    match my_list {
        List::Nil => my_list,
        List::Cons(h, t) => List::Cons(h, Box::new(concat_helper(my_list, t)))
    }
}
```

Now it will not compile:

```
consider borrowing here: `&t`rustcE0308
functions.rs(43, 75): original diagnostic
expected &List<T>, found Box<List<T>, Global>
```

And if I borrow it by changing `t` to `&t` it will say:

```
use of partially moved value: `my_list`
partial move occurs because value has type `Box<List<T>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concat code is correct, it just performs `concat(l2, l1)` instead of `concat(l1, l2)`.

In the `concat_helper()` function, replace `match l2` with `match l1`. Also swap the type definitions for `l1` and `l2` in the arguments to the function.

Comment: Now it does not compile :(. @virchau13

Comment: @chen Please include the error you received. "it does not compile" is not enough to information to help you.

Comment: @Samathingamajig I added it in the edits.